# Why React.Component is not displayed on a particular route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 app pages, that has to be displayed on a particular route: **/dashboard** and **/settings**.

When I login to the app (just press login in the example), I can see a /dashboard Component displayed and the navigation, however when I use the link **/dashboard** or press navigation button - component is not shown.

When There was a single component for Nav + Router, there were no such troubles, but when I've decided to split them, and have navigation only after login - everything changed.

Here is the code for the spilt up Nav and Router components.

```
export class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

[Full Example can be found here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-microservice-c8h40)

Comment: You'd have to wrap your AppContainer with another set of Router and Switch.

Comment: That didn't help to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your missing `<Switch>` and `<Router>` in the AppContainer's index.js. 
I was able to make your example work by adding them here:

```
export class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Making sure to import Switch and Router from 'react-router-dom'

**Edit**
Working copy here: https://7zryx.csb.app/

Adding Login to the dashboard to avoid AppContainer only being rendered if the path is exact '/' and not '/dashboard'.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { AppContainer } from "./components/app-container";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

Navigation - index.js

```
   import React from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import { history } from "../../helpers";

    export class Nav extends React.Component {
      logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem("user");
        history.push("/");
      }

      render() {

// creating a function or state that checks if user is logged in
// if userLoggedIn() === true{

        return (
          <nav className="menu">
            <Link to={"/dashboard"}>Dashboard</Link>
            <Link to={"/settings"}>Settings</Link>
            <Link to={"/login"}>Login</Link>
            <button onClick={() => this.logout()}>Logout</button>
          </nav>
        );
      }
       return (
          <nav className="menu">
            <Link to={"/login"}>Login</Link>
          </nav>
        );
      }
    }
```

AppComponent - index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from "../../helpers";
import { Nav } from "../../components/navigation";
import { Dashboard } from "../../pages/dashboard/";
import { Settings } from "../../pages/settings/";
import { Login } from "../../pages/login/";

export class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I added 'login' to your Nav and structured the Nav to hide all other parts of the site until a successful login. You'll need to create a function or set a state keeping track of the user login so that only the desired components are rendered.

Comment: I've added this, but the behaviour is the same. The code is updated.

Comment: Hm. I'd love to help and make it work however your example code currently isn't compiling..

Comment: Try this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-microservice-c8h40?fontsize=14
Or maybe it has to be forked, in case if my link is broken.

Comment: The problem was about Route path in the main component. it was showing AppContainer only if the path is `exact` '/', but when it's '/dashboard' everything fails. Thank you for trying to help anyway.

Comment: Why don't you move the 'login' component to your nav bar? Then you leave the '/' alone and can navigate to Dashboard, Settings, and Login from AppComponent

Comment: But then I can't make redirect to login from '/', can I? The idea was to protect all the app, before user logged in.

Comment: @Animus does your Nav component work elsewhere? Because I ran Jschriem's code and added a component that I know works where the Nav is and see it on every route.

Comment: Alright, I added 'login' to your Nav and structured the Nav to hide all other parts of the site until a successful login. You'll need to create a function or set a state keeping track of the user login so that only the desired components are rendered.

Comment: Oh, thanks for persistency, Jschriem. I thought there might be a more elegant way, because having a flag for unlogged user is something I've used before. 

@DillanWilding Yes and no, It works fine, when I don't have ProtectedRoute over my AppContainer, but it doesn't when the '/' route is protected. But that seems to be a whole different issue, and probably my structure is bad. I think his final approach is something I'm looking for.

Thank you for the help people!